# How to denormalise data

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I query Table A to produce the result of Table B?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Generally, try to put the minimal reproducible product in your question - linking to an image is hard to use.  Also, always try and show what you've attempted to do so far to get better help =).  It's  a great site but there are some user rules you should google/try and follow to get help here.

Answer (score 0):

That's just a group by and group_concat.

```
select id, group_concat(m_actcode) as m_actcode
from table_a
group by id
```

Group by ID means every record with the same ID is brought together.  group_concat will take all thte values and bring them together in a string (by default with a comma and space).

Comment: any idea on how to set the delimiter of the group_concat?

Comment: Use separator as shown here - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-group_concat-function/

Comment: what about doing the reverse? from table B to Table A.

Comment: Little more complex, but this shows how: https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/splitting-comma-separated-values-in-mysql.  I suggest you accept/close this question and make a new one though if you’re still having trouble :).